# Find no. of points where $f$ and $g$ meet.

Tags: calculus, functions

> If $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x \sin x+ \cos x$ then
>
> (A) $f$ and $g$ agree at no points
>
> (B) $f$ and $g$ agree at exactly one point
>
> (C) $f$ and $g$ agree at exactly two points
>
> (A) $f$ and $g$ agree at more than two points.

Trial: I think I need to find the values of $x$ for which $f(x)=g(x)$. So, I have $x^2-x \sin x- \cos x=0$. How can I solve this ? Please help

Comment: You don't solve it exactly. Begin by drawing the graphs of $f$ and $g$, use your drawing to guess the answer, then try to prove your guess rigorously.

Comment: $|x\sin x +\cos x|\le |x|+1 < x^2$ if $|x|>\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$. So if $x$ satisfies $x\sin x +\cos x=x^2$ then $|x|<\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I can draw $f(x)=x^2$. Please help me to draw $g(x)=x \sin x+ \cos x$.

Comment: $\sin x$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. So $x\sin x$ oscillates between $x$ and $-x$. And for small $x$, $\sin x\approx x$, so $x\sin x\approx x^2$. This should be enough to give you a *very* rough sketch of $x\sin x$. Now you know the grap of $\cos x$. Add it to what you just drew. How does the magnitude of this look for $x$ large, compared to that of $x^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^2 - x\sin x - \cos x$.

- First, you have to notice that: $x^2 - x\sin x - \cos x$ is an *even function* (i.e $f(x) = f(-x)$). And the graph of an even function is symmetric with respect to the *y*-axis. So you just need to count the number of zeroes of $x^2 - x\sin x - \cos x$ for $x > 0$. (Do you know why?)
- When differentiating $x^2 - x\sin x - \cos x$, it turns out to be something very nice: $x (2 - \cos x)$. Since $2 - \cos x$ is always positive, the sign of its derivative depends merely on *x*, so when $x > 0$, it's increasing, and when $x < 0$, it's decreasing.
- Now $f(0) = -1 < 0$. Can you find an $\alpha > 0$, such that $f(\alpha) > 0$?
- Can you go from here?

**Hint**:

- *f* is strictly increasing for $x > 0$.
- The graph of $f$ is symmetric wrt the *y*-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2$ and $x\sin x+\cos x$ are both **even** functions, so the graphs of $y=x^2$ and $y=x\sin x+\cos x$ are symmetric about the $y$ axis. So if we kow the story for $x\ge 0$, we know the story everywhere.

At $x=0$, the curve $y=x^2$ is **below** the curve $y=x\sin x+\cos x$.

But $x^2$, in the long run, is far bigger than $x\sin x+\cos x$. This is clear, but if we want formal proof, observe that for positive $x$, we have $|x\sin x+\cos x|\le x+1$. Thus if $x\gt 2$, then $x^2\gt x+1$.

So the two curves meet at some positive $x$. If you want to be formal, use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Do they meet at more than one positive $x$? The derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$, while the derivative of $x\sin x+\cos x$ is $x\cos x$. Since $x\cos x\lt x$, at any positive $x$ the function $x^2$ grows faster than the function $x\sin x+\cos x$. So once $x^2$ gets above $x\sin x+\cos x$, the function $x\sin x+\cos x$ can never again catch up to $x^2$. A formal proof here would involve the Mean Value Theorem.

Thus the two functions are equal at exactly one positive $x$, and, by symmetry, at exactly one negative $x$.

Answer (score 0):

First, check to get an idea :
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+-+x+sin+x+-+cos+x

Then, you can study the function $\Delta = f-g$. If you show that, say, it is strictly decreasing, then strictly increasing, with negative value at 0 and limits $+\infty$ on $\pm\infty$, can you conclude?

(PS: to make the analysis easier, observe that $\Delta$ is even.)